# Would a copy constructor be at work here?

Tags: c++, reference

```
void setCurrentTransformations(const NodeTransformations& theSet){
    m_currentTransformations=theSet;
}
```

I want to confirm that I am understanding this exactly because `theSet` is going out of scope just after this function gets called.

This is going to actually *copy* `theSet` into `m_currentTransformations`, right? In other words, it is safe, regardless of the scope of `theSet` in the caller.

It's the fact that if this was a pointer instead of a reference, I know it would *not* be safe. But I assume here that it is perfectly fine, and `m_currentTransformations` will copy `theSet` so that it will not matter what happens to the original value that `theSet` references, right?

Comment: This has nothing to do with safety. It's far more fundamentally about *correctness*.

Comment: @KerrekSB that is a rather cryptic comment you made there. care to elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is going to actually copy theSet into m_currentTransformations, right?

Absolutely, this is going to make a copy. However, it is going to do so using the assignment operator of the `NodeTransformations` class, so you may need to be careful of how it is defined. If you define a copy constructor, you usually need an assignment operator and a destructor, too ([that is commonly known as the *rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)).

Comment: "Need" is a little strong.  I have several classes that need copy constructors and assignment but don't need destructors.

Comment: @RyanWitmer You're right, there are [exceptions to the rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15557406/335858), so I should have said "usually need" instead of just "need". Thanks!